# BufferedImage & ColorModel in Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

I am using a image processing library in java to manipulate images.The first step I do is  I read an image and create a `java.awt.Image.BufferedImage` object. I do it in this way,

```
BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageIO.read( new File( filePath ) );
```

The above code creates a `BufferedImage` object with a `DirectColorModel`:

> rmask=ff0000
>   gmask=ff00
>   bmask=ff
>   amask=0.

This is what happens when I run the above code on my macbook.

But when I run this same code on a linux machine (hosted server), this creates a `BufferedImage` object with `ColorModel`:

> pixelBits = 24
>   numComponents = 3
>   color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@c39a20
>   transparency = 1 
>   has alpha = false
>   isAlphaPre = false.

I used the same jpg image in both the cases. I don't know why the `ColorModel` of the same image is different when run on mac and linux. The `ColorModel` for mac has 4 components and the colormodel for linux has 3 components.

There is a problem arising because of this, the image processing library that I use always assumes that there are always 4 components in the ColorModel of the image passed, and it throws an array out of bounds exception when run on the linux box. But on macbook, it runs fine.

Adding a little more info, Once the image is read, I printed out `image.getType()`

- On mac -> it returns `TYPE_INT_RGB` (a value of `1`)
- On linux -> it returns `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` (a value of `5`)

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or there is a problem with the library. Please let me know your thoughts. Also ask me any questions if I am not making sense!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the library.  It should not make assumptions about the `ColorModel` of an image returned from `ImageIO.read`.

Comment: This most likely depends on the Linux version and graphics stack in use.  For more modern graphic stacks with compositing support they will have the alpha channel.  However, as [DirectColorModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/DirectColorModel.htmldocuments) says, some items are final as the JVM needs to inter-operate with the OS/graphic stack to actually display things.  The OPs Linux system was using 3 byte RGB to save memory; if you convert modes (`xrandr`, etc) it would go to another value so the best thing is to convert to your desired model.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know exactly why you're getting two different color models although I believe they're quite the same. The DirectColorModel has 4 components but the alpha mask is 0, so in fact it only has 3 components just like the other one.

I suggest to write a simple helper function which makes sure the image has the right color model before you pass it to this image library. The helper function could make use of http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html or use something like the following code (untested):

```
private static BufferedImage makeCompatible(BufferedImage image) {
  int w = image.getWidth();
  int h = image.getHeight();

  BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
  Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
  g.drawRenderedImage(image, new AffineTransform()); //or some other drawImage function
  g.dispose();

  return result;
}
```

Assuming that the library is able to handle BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR. Otherwise you will have to put something else here. And of course, you could check if the original image already has the right format before converting it.